# Running Autoit script from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autoit

Im trying to run autoitscript from excel vba using a button click.

I wanted to run notepad1.au3 script from an excel sheet.

i copied the script into the same directory as excel sheet.

I wrote the following vba code to run the script.Everything seems to work fine, it takes the path file name etc accurately.

But instead of just running the script, an explorer window pops up ,asking me to locate the script i want to run.

I can browse to the location of the script through the explorer window and select the script file and it will run.

But i want it to run without opening an explorer window.

Any idea where could be the problem?

Thanks

VBA Code:

```
Sub Autoit()

Dim AutoItPath
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileName1 As String
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\notepad1.au3"
MsgBox (FileName)
AutoItPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3" & "\AutoIt3.exe "
MsgBox (AutoItPath)
FileName1 = """" & AutoItPath & """" & """" & FileName & """"
MsgBox (FileName1)
runscript = Shell(FileName1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call is wrong. See the help file:

> Run a script using the interpreter:
>
> AutoIt3.exe [/ErrorStdOut] [/AutoIt3ExecuteScript] filename [params ...]
>
> Execute the AutoIt3 script 'filename' with optional parameters

example command: `"'" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe " /AutoIt3ExecuteScript "..path\notepad1.au3" & "'"`